# Keyboard " Ctrl + / " shortcout issue

Tags: google-apps-script, windows-10, ide, keyboard-shortcuts, opera

I'm currently working on some scritps on GAS IDE. There, the single-line comment shortcut is "Ctrl + /". My keyboard layout is Spanish so my only way to write down a '/' is "Shift + 7". As this IDE is framed in a browser, browser shortcuts are more relevant and this shortcut just changes between tabs.

Using Opera browser on Windows 10.

Any idea of how to perform this shorcut?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you on Windows you can use Autohokey https://www.autohotkey.com/ and script something like this: `+^7:: send {ctrl down}/{ctrl up}` which mean to send `Ctlr+/` as soon as you press `Ctrl+Shift+7`

Comment: @Rubén Edited. Sorry for the lack on info